# How can I add dependencies to project build path dynamically by the coding?

Tags: build, eclipse-plugin, path

In the application I´m helping to develop (an Eclipse plugin) we need to provide a dialog with a list of possible dependencies that user´s Eclipse project might have. After having chosen the dependencies Eclipse will download it from our repository and we´d like to automatically put them in the project build path.

How can I do it???

The only thing I found was editing the project properties using Eclipse Wizard but in this approach the users would have to add all the dependencies manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as @jwhy suggests, that all of the projects are maven projects, then your users can install [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e).  And you can let maven handle dependency management.

If, however, users are not guaranteed to have maven installed, then you would need a custom solution.  There is an extension point called `org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathContainerInitializer`.  This allows you to add a single entry to the classpaths of user projects and then programmatically control how that classpath resolves into multiple entries at runtime and compile time.  An example is the JRE classpath container.

Answer (score 1):

If you can prove that all target workstations have/can get Maven, it's very easy to solve this using the [Maven dependency](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) plugin, which will automatically add a section called 'Maven dependencies' to your Eclipse project tree.